# Dynamically evaluate values to pass as props in React, in a efficient way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dynamic, react-props

I need to dynamically evaluate which piece of state I want to send as props to a child component (modal). My current code is given below. The state ' selectedSection' state determines which section of the page is in focus, and its used to determine the appropriate states related to that section that I need to pass as props to the child.

My question is, is what I am currently doing a good approach, i.e. invoking a function to determine what to send in as props? Are there more efficient ways of doing this, like using useCallback to wrap the function(I am not fully familiar with useCallback, is this a good scenario to use it?), or changing the approach completely? Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
const getCustomeDatesPropForPeriodModal = () => {
    let datesForModal;
    switch(selectedSection) {
      case 'section1':
        datesForModal = section1Dates; //a piece of state
        break;
      case 'section2':
        datesForModal = section2Dates;
        break;
      default:
        datesForModal = [null, null];
      }
      return datesForModal;
  }

<AnalyticsPeriodSelectionModal
  customDates={getCustomeDatesPropForPeriodModal()}
/>
```

Comment: `useMemo` would be a more appropriate hook to use if you needed to memoize the value sent as a prop (*for performance, if there was an issue*). What you have seems fine to me.

Comment: Really depends on how the rest of the data is structured, but instead of having multiple states, you could turn the 'section1Dates' and 'section2Dates' into one array and have an integer for 'selectedSection', then reference the dates using 'selectedSection' as an index. This would be make things more scalable if that could be an issue in the future. If you're happy with what you have, then it looks good to me though.

Comment: @PaulMartin Good advice, the example I posted here is a scaled down version of my actual code, and yeah, the number of states that I am dealing with right now is getting out of hand. 5 sections in total, with a lot of  similar state pieces for each of those sections. A restructuring would definitely make it more efficient I would assume.